# How to make "maven update project..." a "launch configuration" in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, m2e

I am working on some maven project in eclipse (Mars.2 Release (4.5.2))
I find myself constantly doing: maven clean install, project clean, maven update, debug as/debug on server, all require mouse clicks or keyboard shortcut to launch one after another.

It looks like I can use "launch group" as a potential solution to run these common tasks in a script. But I can only add "Launch configuration" to a launch group, the tasks such as "maven -> update project..." are not "launch configuration" so it can not be added into a launch group.

Also "Debug As -> Debug on Server" is not a launch configuration.

I guess what  I am asking is to group common eclipse tasks (anything that can be launched through eclipse UI), execute the tasks sequentially, and potentially controls the following tasks based on the outputs of each task. (sounded like I am asking for a makefile).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can script it using [EASE](https://www.eclipse.org/ease/) (Eclipse Advanced Scripting Environment)

BTW: 4.5.2 is already quite old, it might be a good idea to upgrade first.